Revalidation tags management best practices
In Next.js 13/14 (app-router) its possible to set revalidation tags for each fetch request in order to invalidate the cached fetch data the next time a fetch happens as stated in the docs.
It is useful but once you get a lot of revalidation tags for different purposes and the need to invalidate many at once it can be tedious to keep track of your tags name/syntax.
my tagging system so far looks like this:
fetch("https://acme.com/api/posts/1234", {
  next: {
    tags: [ "post:1234", "posts", "*" ]
  }
});


posts:1234 tag is used to invalidate just the post 1234 cached data.
posts is used to invalidate all posts cached data.
* is a tag i have to put on each fetch in order to purge the entire data cache.

This works but i'm wondering if there's any best practices to manage revalidation tags.

Interesting! The internet lacks best practices or guidance for this.
